# Distinct to one or more columns only in a join query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a query that join three tables, let's say its `Transaction`, `TransactionIcdDetails` and `TransactionMedicineDetails` and each of them linked via id of the transaction

My tables look like this:

**Transaction**

```
id | price | transaction_date
------------------------------
01 | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
```

**TransactionIcdDetails**

```
id | transaction_id | icd
------------------------------
01 | 01             | ICD01
02 | 01             | ICD02
```

**TransactionMedicineDetails**

```
id | transaction_id | medicine
------------------------------
01 | 01             | MDC01
02 | 01             | MDC02
```

And I want to make Query that link them into one, i used query design to achieve this goal, however the result is look something like this:

```
id |  icd  | medicine | price | transaction_date
------------------------------
01 | ICD01 | MDC01    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
01 | ICD01 | MDC02    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
01 | ICD02 | MDC01    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
01 | ICD02 | MDC02    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
```

Notice that the `icd` is repeated twice, it's the same with the `medicine`.
The output **that i want** is should be looks like this:

```
id |  icd  | medicine | price | transaction_date
------------------------------
01 | ICD01 | MDC01    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
01 | ICD02 | MDC02    | $3.00 | 23/09/2015
```

How can i make query like this? it's seems i can't use `Distinct` to few columns only.
If you think i'm doing it wrong, feel free to correct the way how i should implement this.

**Update**
I could make it work by create a relation between `TransactionMedicineDetails.Id` and `TransactionIcdDetails.Id`.

However, it all goes wrong when i have unequal number of details, lets say i have 3 rows of `TransactionMedicineDetails` and 2 rows of `TransactionIcdDetails` for a single `Transaction` (or vice versa), the one without pair wont appear on query.

Any idea how to make them all appear?

Comment: Your design of the tables is not right. You should make any linkage between **TransactionIcdDetails** and **TransactionMedicineDetails**.

Comment: So, i should make a relationship between **TransactionIcdDetails** and **TransactionMedicineDetails**? like link their id?

or create a new table that link them? if so, I thought **Transaction** table is already linked them

Comment: Hard to say, since we don't know what data you store in TransactionIcdDetails and TransactionMedicineDetails.

Comment: Yes, transaction_id in **TransactionMedicineDetails** should be changed into transaction_detail_id which reference id of **TransactionIcdDetails**

Comment: Or add transaction_detail_id in **TransactionMedicineDetails**. Something like that.

Comment: If you don't want the schema change of existing tables, you can add a new table to state the relationship between **TransactionIcdDetails** and **TransactionMedicineDetails**. As I can see your desired output implies this.

Comment: @jarlh it just a text, in each transaction (on clinic), a patient should have at least one disease (icd) and one medicine that defined under those 2 tables.

Comment: Can you update your sample data, different prices etc for different products. (And also the wanted result according to those changes.)

Comment: @daniel i could make it work by creating relarion between both `id` on each details tables, however there is one problem, i will update my question

Comment: I think in current scenario, you can use the combination of transaction_id and id, if schema will not change. As your last statement, when the record count is different, implement full outer logic.

Comment: you shall show the schema changes of the tables for the relationship added, and your proposed script. just state the problem is not enough for people to provide suggestion.